# Biztalk Cluster Servers

Tags: biztalk, cluster-computing, biztalk2006r2

we used to have 1 biztalk 2006R2 32bit server. We recently upgraded it to Enterprise. But because our traffic size we didn't have enough power and memory with only one. So we also recently installed a second biztalk server, a 2006R2 64-bit, and we put them in a shared cluster. Since then a problem arose, actually two but I'm guessing they probably are connected. One of our (19) host instances keeps getting in the "stopped" status. This host instance is mainly connected with TCP ports. We have a script which checks if host instances are in the stopped state and starts them again, but this obviously has very little use since it keeps resetting to the stopped state. There also is an error in our event viewer, namely:

```
Faulting application btsntsvc.exe, version 3.6.1404.0, stamp 4674b0a4, faulting module kernel32.dll, version 5.2.3790.4480, stamp 49c51f0a, debug? 0, fault address 0x0000bef7.
```

Anyone has any idea?

Thanks

Comment: It seems as tho the problem lay in the configuration of each sendport which used TCP settings, after changing something in each sendport, saving it and then changing it back again it somehow changed the saved configuration and the problem is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having automated scripts to restart the host instance is not a good idea IMO, you need to get to the bottom of the problem. It looks like a known issue and a hot fix is availble. Worth lookint at this KB http://support.microsoft.com/kb/978059